# Probability dice don't match and expected difference

Tags: probability

The four musketeers decide to send a bouquet of roses to Snow White for
her Birthday. They toss a die each and contribute as many roses to the
bouquet as their die shows.

(i) What is the probability that at least two out of the four musketeers will
contribute different numbers of flowers?

For this part I assumed the probability of two number of flowers not matching is

$$\frac{6}{6}\times \frac{5}{6}\times\frac{4}{6}\times\frac{3}{6}$$

For the first roll some number will be rolled so probability 
is 1. For the second roll  theres a 1/6 chance the roll will match the first  so a 5/6 chance is won't match. For the third there's a 4/6 chance it won't match the 1<sup>st</sup> or 2<sup>nd</sup> roll and then with the 4<sup>th</sup> roll there's a 3/6 chance it will match one of the others.
Similarly for the probability that 3  and 4 choose different numbers of flowers I get

$$\frac{6}{6}\times \frac{5}{6}\times\frac{4}{6}\times\frac{3}{6}$$
and

$$\frac{6}{6}\times \frac{5}{6}\times\frac{4}{6}\times\frac{3}{6}$$I think this isn't right.  Do i instead need to work with 1 - probability of same number.

(ii) Let X be a random variable representing the maximal out of the four
contributions, and let Y stands for the minimal one. Calculate the value
of joint probability, PXY (3, 2), that X = 3 AND Y = 2.

For the number of possibilities that satisify this we are selecting 4 outcomes (4 dice rolls) and there are 2 possibilities for each outcome, either a 2 or a 3, so there would be 2<sup>4</sup> possibilities and a sample space of 6<sup>4</sup> so the probability is 2<sup>4</sup>/6<sup>4</sup>?

(iii) Calculate the expected difference between the maximal and the minimal contributions, E(X − Y ).

I'm not too sure about this one, but would it be, the probability of having a minimum of 2 would be 5<sup>4</sup>/6<sup>4</sup> and the probability of the maximum being 3 is 3<sup>4</sup>/6<sup>4</sup> so would he expected difference be

$$(2)(5^4/6^4)-(3)(3^4/6^4)$$

Comment: I got around to (iii) - completing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For (i) You started out with the right approach, but the wrong question, although your last remark is correct.  The opposite possibility is that all four have the same number which is $P=(\frac{1}{6})^3$, so the probability you want is $1-(\frac{1}{6})^3=0.99537037037037$

For (ii)   You need to subtract the probabilities of all 3 or all 2 which $\frac{2}{6^4}$.

For (iii) Let $Z=X-Y,\ E(Z)=\sum_{z=0}^5zP(Z=z)$.  To get $P(Z=z)$, consider all pairs $(X,Y)$ where $X-Y=z$.  For each $z$ there are $6-z$ such pairs and the probabilities are the same for each pair.   To get the probability for each pair for a specific $z$, $P(Y=y,X=x)=P(Y\le y,X\ge x)-P(Y\lt y,X\ge x)-P(Y\le y,X\gt x)+P(Y\lt y,X\gt x)$

$=
{\frac{z+1}{6}-2\frac{z}{6}+\frac{z-1}{6}(see\ note).}$

Therefore $E(Z)=\sum_{z=0}^5 z(6-z)(\frac{z+1}{6}-2\frac{z}{6}+\frac{z-1}{6})=5-\frac{1958}{1296}=3.489197530864198.$

Note: The terms where the numerator $=0$ or $-1$ are omitted.

Answer (score 0):

In part (ii), you also need to be sure that not all the rolls are all $2$ or $3$. As such, your answer should be

$$
(2/6)^4 - (1/6)^4 - (1/6)^4
$$

Since there is a $(1/6)^4$ chance of getting all 2, which is equal to chance of getting all 3.

This can also be done by multinational experiment.

$$
\sum_{n=1}^3 \frac{4!}{n!(4-n)!}(1/6)^4
$$

In part (iii), the dice rolls is uniform with a pmf of $1/6$ for $i = 1,2,...,6$. As such, the cdf is

$$
F(y) = y/6
$$

Notice that $P(Y_{max} < y)$ occurs only if all other rolls are less than $y$ also. Therefore

$$
P(Y_{max} \leq y) = F(y)^4 = (y/6)^4
$$

As such, using $G(y)$ and $H(y)$ to simplify notation, we have

$$
G(y) = P(Y_{max} = y) = P(Y_{max} \leq y) - P(Y_{max} \leq (y-1)) = (y/6)^4 - ((y-1)/6)^4
$$

Similarly, since $P(Y_{min} \geq y) = 1-(1-F(y))^4$, we have

$$
H(y) = P(Y_{min} = y) = P(Y_{min} \leq y) - P(Y_{min} \leq (y-1)) = ((7-y)/6)^4 - ((6-y)/6)^4
$$

Therefore, summing all possible values of y (1 through 6).

$$E(X-Y) = E(X) - E(Y) = \sum yG(y) - \sum yH(y) \\= 5.24459876543 - 1.75540123457 = 3.48919753086
$$

Comment: $G(y)$ and $H(y)$ are as defined independently.  However don't you need to take into account min $\le$ max?

Comment: I finally got around to (iii) and got the same answer as you did.

Comment: Did you use a similar method or completely different?

Comment: I didn't try to compare methods, but I presume there must be some similarity, since we got the same answer.  As you may have noticed from my previous comments I was concerned about the dependency between $X$ and $Y$, so I tried to explicitly include the connection in my analysis.

Comment: I must have accidentally overlooked that comment, whoops. Do you mind sharing your solution?

Comment: My solution is above, included in the first answer to the original question.  I already had answered (i) and (ii) and just edited my answer to include (iii).

Answer (score 0):

Hint on (iii).

By linearity of expectation: $\mathbb E(X-Y)=\mathbb EX-\mathbb EY$.

What follows makes it more easy to find $\mathbb EX$ and $\mathbb EY$.

---

If $Z$ takes values in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ then: $$\mathbb EZ=\sum_{k=1}^6kP(Z=k)=\sum_{k=1}^6\sum_{r=1}^kP(Z=k)=\sum_{r=1}^6\sum_{k=r}^6P(Z=k)=\sum_{r=1}^6P(Z\geq r)$$

Applying this on $X$ we find:$$\mathbb EX=\sum_{r=1}^6P(X\geq r)=\sum_{r=1}^6\left(1-P(X<r)\right)=6-\sum_{r=1}^6P(X<r)$$where $P(X<r)$ is quite easy to find.

Also you apply this on $Y$ where $P(Y\geq r)$ is quite easy to find.